# Is there an implied be verb in the sentence "American workers facing or are facing"?

Tags: style-manuals

> American workers facing a less prosperous future than their parents’ generation have gotten the message—or at least a version of it.

Can anyone please explain the structure? Is there any implied be verb after workers, like workers are facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing "who were" in "The park was empty except for a group of people who were stretching, jogging, and doing Tai Chi"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203858/removing-who-were-in-the-park-was-empty-except-for-a-group-of-people-who-were)

Answer (score 1):

> [*American workers facing a less prosperous future than their parents’*
> *generation*] *have gotten the message.*

No: the bracketed element is a non-finite clause functioning as subject of the sentence. It's quite common for non-finite clauses, as well as finite ones, to function as subject.

Within that clause the gerund-participial clause "facing a less prosperous future than their parents’ generation" is modifying "American workers".

In your example the gerund-participial clause is the semantic equivalent of the relative clause in *American workers who are facing a less prosperous future than their parents’ generation.*

But it's not called a relative clause since there is no possibility of it containing a relative phrase (cf. **American workers who facing a less prosperous future than their* *parents’ generation*).

Answer (score 0):

> American workers *facing a less prosperous future than their parents’ generation* have gotten the message

*"facing a less prosperous future than their parents’ generation"* is what is known as a reduced relative clause.

In full, it is

American workers ***who are*** facing a less prosperous future than their parents’ generation have gotten the message.

("American workers ***are*** facing a less prosperous future than their parents’ generation have gotten the message." is wrong for obvious reasons.)

Comment: Greybeard thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't you think this question suits English Language Learners site better? It's interesting that you kindly left answer for this. I have no clue what your criteria is